# Installing pip package through .ebextensions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, virtualenv, ebextensions

I am having trouble installing the package `psycopg2` through `ebextensions`.

**00_software.config**

```
packages:
  yum:
    git: []
    htop: []
  pip:
    psycopg2: []
```

**01_setup_pg_activity.config**

```
commands:
    clone:
        command: git clone https://github.com/dalibo/pg_activity.git
    install_psycopg2:
        command: cd pg_activity && python setup.py install
```

Alternatively, I have also tried this to no avail

```
commands:
    clone:
        command: git clone https://github.com/dalibo/pg_activity.git
    install_psycopg2:
        command: pip install psycopg2
    install_psycopg2:
        command: cd pg_activity && python setup.py install
```

The other software installs but pip packages will not

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pg_activity", line 4, in <module>
    __import__('pkg_resources').run_script('pg-activity==1.6.1', 'pg_activity')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 742, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1510, in run_script
    exec(script_code, namespace, namespace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pg_activity-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/pg_activity", line 42, in <module>

ImportError: No module named psycopg2
```

I have to manually go in and run `sudo pip install psycopg2` for it to correctly install. How can I do this in the build process?

Comment: Is it amazon linux 1 or 2? Also I assume its python env?

Comment: 2 I'm pretty sure. the beanstalk environment is RoR but I have all the essential things needed for python installed on it already

Comment: If you are using a virtual environment and EB CLI, simply creating `requirements.txt` will be enough while the virtual environment is active. EB CLI handles the package installations on deployment.

Comment: @ikonuk thanks this is the only thing that worked for me if you want to post as an answer ill accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a virtual environment and [EB CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3.html), simply creating `requirements.txt` will be enough while the virtual environment is active. EB CLI handles the package installations on deployment.

Answer (score 1):

Using EB with AL2 (python env; haven't tested on RoR), **successfully installed** `pg_activity`.

For packages (only psycopg2 shown) I had

```
packages: 
    yum:
        python-psycopg2: []
```

And the `commands` config file was (20_setup_pg_activity.config):

```
commands:
    05_clone:
        command: git clone https://github.com/dalibo/pg_activity.git    
    10_install_pg_activity:
        command: cd pg_activity && python setup.py install
```

Following the env setup, I logged into the EB instance to check if  `pg_activity` exists (only part shown):

```
ec2-user@ip-172-31-82-127 ~]$ pg_activity --help
Usage: pg_activity [options]

htop like application for PostgreSQL server activity monitoring.

Options:
  --version             show program's version number and exit
  -U USERNAME, --username=USERNAME
```